# Collider (OnTriggerEnter) dosnt work in android Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game for mobile , I have one collider that enables a bool , when I collide with `OnTriggerEnter` or `OnTriggerStay` in the editor all works, but when I build and use it on android it doesn't work, but, I used it in other phones and it works sometimes, and sometimes not. I don't know, I'm getting crazy.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.transform.gameObject.name);
    if (other.transform.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < enemy.Count; i++)
        {
            enemy[i].IsActive = true ;
            Debug.Log(enemy[i].IsActive);
        }
    }
}
```

some videos :   works in editor (without device): [Works in editor](https://gyazo.com/12b68d3af4a0e2ab0cb06e5ab9ea0b3a)
doesn't work in android : [doesn't work in android](https://gyazo.com/6c4bce0f9f56e3191a3077f42992a152)

It have a collider with `OnTriggerEnter` , my player have a tag attached, it have a Rigidbody, in editor the debug shows the name and the is active but when I plug my phone and use it in the editor it doesn't work and shows nothing.

The collider doesn't show nothing when I plug my phone and test it in unity editor.

Edit: Now if I instantiate my player ,feels like all work, but sometimes I need to recreate other time for the colliders start to do something.

Edit2: I discovered that `abilityButton.onClick.AddListener(player.GetComponentInChildren<IAbility>().Ability);`
line is blocking the events ,i guess.

Sorry for my english, and thanks for the help.

Comment: First.. you should always compare strings with "Equals" method and not "==" operator.

Comment: what @rootpanthera meant was to use the line `if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))` instead of what you have

Comment: if it's a collider does it work?

Comment: dosnt matter, , i recently discovered that  my button on screen stops the other events, abilityButton.onClick.AddListener(player.GetComponentInChildren<IAbility>().Ability);   thats stops the colliders i dont know why.